# Is querying for IS NULL necessary in this CASE expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got this case statement:

```
CASE 
  WHEN SecondScriptKind_ID IS NULL THEN 0
  WHEN SecondScriptKind_ID IN (@SqlQuery, @SqlScript) THEN 1
  ELSE 0 
END
```

Is the `WHEN SecondScriptKind_ID IS NULL` necessary in this case?

Both @SqlQuery and @SqlScript are guaranteed to contain values (NOT NULL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `ANSI_NULLS` is set `on`, it is not necessary: even if `@SqlQuery` or `@SqlScript` happen to be `NULL`, the `IN` is not going to match a `NULL` `SecondScriptKind_ID` to that list. In other words, the condition

```
NULL IN (NULL, 123)
```

evaluates to `NULL`. The only reason to keep an explicit `NULL` check there would be if you wanted to return a different number for `NULL`, say, a negative 1.

Comment: @podiluska As far as SQL Server 2012 is concerned, yes ([demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/6346)).

Comment: Actually that is not quite correct. `NULL IN (NULL, 123)` evaluates to `NULL`. Comparing anything to `NULL` results in `NULL`. Because it is still not `true`, so it will behave like `false` in most cases (like in above example) but it's still not `false`, and if you put `NOT` in front you will still get `NULL` (and nothing in select) - [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/6349)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `set ansi_nulls off`

Comment: @podiluska [In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I know. But your answer says that it is not necessary without knowing the specific configuration

Comment: @podiluska I don't think it's necessary to mention a feature that has been deprecated back in 2005 in an answer to a question posted in the middle of 2013.